# Working with SQL Server using service accounts

Tags: sql-server, windows

Please let me know if I am missing something.

I am building a database on a dev system using my Windows credentials. Now my manager told me to migrate the database to another environment, but only gave a service account access to the database, and told me to use the service account. My windows credentials don't have access to the database.

I have some SSIS packages that push and pull data to this database that I can configure to make use of the service account, that's fine. But how do I access the database to view data, or test stored procedures and functions or make changes using only a service account?

The service account is an Active Directory account.

He is adamant that the service account is sufficient.

The environment is making use of SQL Server 2012.

Comment: is the service account an Active Directory account?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have also edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

you can run the Sql Server Management Studio as a different User, and enter the service account credentials, you should have all the permissions granted for this account

please check the following link:

https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/419-run-different-user.html